# Arithmetics with local variables in a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got the following trigger for my table:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `orders_sneakers_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `orders_sneakers` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

declare currentTotalMoney decimal(13,2);
declare newSneakerPrice decimal(13,2);
declare oldSneakerPrice decimal(13,2);
declare updatedTotalMoney decimal(13,2);

select totalMoney
into currentTotalMoney
from orders 
where orders.id = new.id;

select price
into newSneakerPrice
from sneakers 
where id = new.sneakerId;

select price
into oldSneakerPrice
from sneakers 
where id = old.sneakerId;

set updatedTotalMoney := currentTotalMoney + newSneakerPrice * new.sneakerQty - oldSneakerPrice * old.sneakerQty;

update orders set totalMoney = updatedTotalMoney where id = new.id;

END
```

`totalMoney` from `orders` is `decimal(13,2)` as well.

The problem is that `updatedTotalMoney` does not seem to appear as I expect it to be. It gets calculated in the different way from what it looks like. It works perfectly fine without the **subtraction part**, but with it weird things happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add sample data, actual result, and desired result.

Comment: @Andrew, for instance, I have got 2 sneakers in the order ($100.49 and $129.38). We have totalMoney = $229.87. Then, we update our data, and now we have 2 of each sneakers, which means totalMoney must be $459.74 now, but it remains $229.87.

Comment: Please add sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, actual and desired outputs - as table-formatted text.

Comment: @Akina, I am working with SQLKata ORM for C#.